# Flickering video for tkinter video

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, tkinter

I am trying to make a simple play/pause application in tkinter. Basically I want to show a video and have a play/pause button underneath.

So, after some research I found this suitable post to show a video using tkinter and opencv:
[to show video streaming inside frame in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50922175/to-show-video-streaming-inside-frame-in-tkinter)

When using the code, given in the accepted answer to show a video, there is no problem and I don't see any flickering. Here is the code:

```
# import the necessary packages
from __future__ import print_function
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import cv2


root = tk.Tk()
# Create a frame
app = tk.Frame(root, bg="white")
app.grid()
# Create a label in the frame
lmain = tk.Label(app)
lmain.grid()

# Capture from camera
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(r'PATH_TO_VIDEO_FILE')

# function for video streaming
frame_number = 0
def video_stream(): 
    global frame_number
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frame_number)
    success, frame = cap.read()
    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
    img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    lmain.imgtk = imgtk
    lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
    lmain.after(1, video_stream) 

    frame_number += 1

video_stream()
root.mainloop()
```

Now, I slightly altered the code to be able to use the grid manager and add a play button:

```
# import the necessary packages

from __future__ import print_function
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

import cv2


class PhotoBoothApp:
    def __init__(self, path_to_video):
        # initialize the root window
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.title("Video_Player")
        self.videocap = cv2.VideoCapture(path_to_video)
        self.frame_number = 0

        # Initalize
        self.videocap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, self.frame_number)
        success, self.frame = self.videocap.read()
        cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(self.frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
        self.img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
        self.imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.img)
        # Show frames
        self.picture_label = tk.Label(self.window, image=self.imgtk, relief=tk.RIDGE).grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.btn_next_image=tk.Button(self.window, text="Play", width=50, bg ="green",command=self.video_stream).grid(row=1,column=0)

        self.window.mainloop()





    def video_stream(self):

        self.videocap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, self.frame_number)
        sucess, frame = self.videocap.read()
        cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
        img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
        self.imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        self.picture_label = tk.Label(self.window, image=self.imgtk, relief=tk.RIDGE).grid(row=0, column=0)
        # Update Frame Number to display
        self.frame_number = self.frame_number + 1
        self.window.after(1, self.video_stream) 


ph = PhotoBoothApp(r'PATH_TO_FILE')
```

The problem is that when I execute the above code, the video flickers as if tkinter need to reload something in-between frames. I have no clue why this happens.

P.S. This post here [Flickering video in opencv-tkinter integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48364168/flickering-video-in-opencv-tkinter-integration) did not help me.

Comment: There is a big difference between the sample and your code. In the sample, only one label widget is created, and new video frames are configured to that same label. Your code, on the other hand, is creating a new label every millisecond.

Comment: @HenryYik Thank you for your valuable input and your analysis! I don't see another way to update the frame in the label. Do you see a method ?

Comment: That method is in the sample, which is using `label.configure(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make two changes: split your `self.picture_label` line to create a proper reference to your `Label` object, and then use `self.picure_label.config(...)` to change the image.

```
class PhotoBoothApp:
    def __init__(self, path_to_video):
        # initialize the root window
        ...
        self.picture_label = tk.Label(self.window, image=self.imgtk, relief=tk.RIDGE)
        self.picture_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        ...

    def video_stream(self):
        ...
        img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
        self.imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        self.picture_label.config(image=self.imgtk)
        # Update Frame Number to display
        self.frame_number = self.frame_number + 1
        self.window.after(1, self.video_stream)

ph = PhotoBoothApp(r'PATH_TO_FILE')
```

Comment: Thank you so much !! This worked for me ! Do I need to use this .config() function for every label that I want to update ? Say, if I have a text label, and I want to update just the color ?

Comment: For `tk.Label`, yes.

Comment: Thanks you for the explanation !